# Static iframe preview

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a site with lot's of different online games i have created. And i'm now trying to create a site with all the games listed with a little picture/preview of inside the game. I could just snap a picture of every game, but it would be much more convenient for a code to just show a static preview of the game. So is there such a code that can do that?

Comment: well doubt you can do it with an iframe..... write code that automates snapping a photo.

Comment: Yeah that could be also the answer. It would be nice to get an examble of such a code, because i'm not too good in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use, for example jQuery, to run a HTTP GET request against the url of the page where your games are located, and inject the HTML that comes in the XHR response in the iframe?

If you figure out your [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) policies, and **assuming that each of your games displays some sort of static HTML before you start playing**, you should be able to get a static preview by running something like:

```
var url = 'http://example.com'
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
// jQuery HTTP get request
$.get(url, function(html){
   // Parse response here to get static html game preview.
   console.log('%j', html);
   var frameDoc = iframe.document;
    // IE
    if(iframe.contentWindow){
       frameDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    }
    frameDoc.open();
    frameDoc.writeln(html);
    frameDoc.close();
})
```

Comment: What response should i parse there? I haven't used jQuery before.

Comment: @piuhamies You should parse the html (string) that gets passed into the function as an argument. Check the output of the `console.log()`. You really don't need to use any jQuery to parse the response. If you do not want to use jQuery at all, you could start your HTTP Get request using pure vanilla Javascript (Ajax) as well: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp